# vala Webkit.WebView DOM manipulation

Tags: webview, webkit, vala

How can manipulate the DOM tree in webkit2gtk-4.0?

Old version:

```
WebKit.DOM.Document doc = get_dom_document();
WebKit.DOM.Element el = doc.create_element("div");
el.append_child(doc.create_text_node(color));
((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) el).add_event_listener("dblclick", (Callback) on_div_clicked, false, this);
doc.body.insert_before(el, null);
```

compile:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg libsoup-2.4 --pkg webkitgtk-3.0
```

New version compile:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-4.0
```

error:

```
error: The symbol `DOM' could not be found
    private WebKit.DOM.Document get_document()
```

http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0/WebKit.DOM.Document
How to add webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `--pkg webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0` to your compile flags.