# How to add event listener?

Tags: webkit, closures, addeventlistener, vala

simple code:

```cs
((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure ("click", on_enter, false);

void on_enter() {

}
```

valac error:

```
error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from `on_enter' to `GLib.Closure'
```

Here is the full code example:

```cs
private void on_click(WebKit.DOM.EventTarget target, WebKit.DOM.Event event)
{
  try
  {
    //var image = (WebKit.DOM.HTMLImageElement)target;
    //image.set_attribute("class", "clickable-img-hover");
  }
  catch(GLib.Error e)
  {
  }
}

public static void webkit_web_extension_initialize (WebKit.WebExtension web_extension)
{
  string PROG = "[webkit2_webextension_minimal_so.so] ";    

  print(PROG + "PLUGIN activated\n");

  web_extension.page_created.connect((extension, web_page)=> {
      print(PROG + "SIGNAL: page_created\n");
      try {
        var dom = web_page.get_dom_document();

        WebKit.DOM.Element img = dom.create_element("img");
        img.set_attribute("src", "file:///home/o/avatar.png");
        img.set_attribute("alt", "avatar-1.jpg");
        ((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure("click", on_click, false);
        dom.body.insert_before(img, null);
      } catch (FileError e) {
        stdout.printf ("Message: \"%s\"\n", e.message);
            stdout.printf ("Error code: FileError.EXIST = %d\n", e.code);
            stdout.printf ("FileErrors identification: %" + uint32.FORMAT + "\n", e.domain);
        }

      web_page.send_request.connect((request)=> {
          if(request.uri.has_prefix("http://www.google") || request.uri.has_prefix("data")){
            print(PROG + "SIGNAL: send request [REJECTED] " + request.uri + "\n");
            return true;  // true => block query
          }
          print(PROG + "SIGNAL: send request " + request.uri + "\n");
          return false;
        });

      return;
    });
}
```

Compile with:

```
valac --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0 --library=webext webext.vala -H webext.h -X -fPIC -X -shared -o webext.so
```

How to add event listener?

PS: This is a follow up question to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821199/vala-webkit-webview-dom-manipulation).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation for the method](https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0/WebKit.DOM.EventTarget.add_event_listener_with_closure.html):

```cs
public bool add_event_listener_with_closure (
    string event_name,
    owned EventTargetFunc handler,
    bool use_capture
)
```

The second argument is `owned EventTargetFunc handler`.

So looking at the [documentation of the delegate type](https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0/WebKit.DOM.EventTargetFunc.html):

```cs
public delegate void EventTargetFunc (EventTarget target, Event event)
```

Your method does not have this delgate type.

So you probably have to fix your method signature to something like:

```cs
void on_enter (EventTarget target, Event event) {

}
```

Comment: delegate void on_enter(WebKit.DOM.Element element, WebKit.DOM.Event event);
and
     ((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure("click", on_enter());
result:
> error: invocation not supported in this context

Comment: Two things. First, EventTargetFunc is already defined, it is a function signature that any delegate has to match. `delegate void on_enter(...);` is creating a new delegate type `on_enter`. That's not what you want to do, use the existing type. Second, `on_enter()` invokes (or calls) the delegate. You just want to pass the function so it can be invoked later, so just use `on_enter` without the parentheses.

Comment: For the `invocation not supported` error, see also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187122/how-do-i-connect-a-custom-function-to-the-clicked-action-of-a-gtk-button

Comment: Ok, again:

delegate void on_enter();
on_enter test = () => {}
((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure("click", test);

return valac:
error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from `on_enter' to `GLib.Closure'

I just want to call a function when I click on an element. Change the old version:

((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) el).add_event_listener("dblclick", (Callback) on_enter, false, this);

Comment: Jens advice is to change your simple code from `((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure ("click", on_enter, false); void on_enter() {}` to `((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure ("click", on_enter, false); void on_enter(EventTarget target, Event event) {}`

Comment: return:
error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from `on_enter' to `GLib.Closure'

Comment: Here are a couple of examples: [WebKit Javascript extension](https://gist.github.com/geoffjay/dc84e642d412f403b33ae666812761fa#file-extension-vala-L90) and [FeedReader/WebExtension/webextension.vala](https://github.com/jangernert/FeedReader/blob/master/WebExtension/webextension.vala#L81) Looking at those you should probably use `((WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure ("click", on_enter, false); void on_enter(WebKit.DOM.EventTarget target, WebKit.DOM.Event event) {}`

Comment: Yes, I do exactly the same thing... https://pastebin.com/jnH2jtvn 
valac --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0 --library=webext webext.vala -H webext.h -X -fPIC -X -shared -o webext.so

compile error:
error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from `on_click' to `GLib.Closure'

Comment: Your pastebin example compiles fine for me with both Vala 0.30.2 and Vala compiled from master

Comment: A saw a similar example on SO, where the OP was explicitly casting the event handler (like `(WebKit.DOM.EventTarget) img).add_event_listener_with_closure ("click", (Closure) on_enter, false);`). Maybe this was necessary in some older Vala version?

Comment: Ah I see now, that this was your original question of which this one here is a follow up. I'm going to add this to the question.

Comment: Please tell us which version of the Vala compiler you are using.